# Synchronizing file processing threads across servers in linux

Tags: linux, file, daemon

I need to build a linux service/daemon which processes files.  This daemon will most likely be multi-threaded and most likely be running on more than one node.  What would be the best way to synchronize the threads of all daemons such that no two threads are processing the same file?

A couple ideas came to mind but wondering whether there is a better approach as I'm new to linux.

1. Create a directory structure such that only one daemon processes a directory.   The daemon itself should be able to easily synchronize the threads within it such that no two threads are processing the same file.
2. Determine some mechanism using open() and maybe file attributes such that once a process can successfully open a file exclusively when the file is in some state, maybe some file attribute not set yet, the state is changed, by changing some file attribute, and that daemon can process the file knowing that no other daemon will process it.
3. Come up with a naming convention such that the names are somewhat equally distributed across some numerical name.  Each daemon could then be configured to process some modulo number.

Example: file name = 987654321

We have a daemon running on two nodes.  The configuration for each daemon would indicate the number of daemons and which modulo the daemon should process.  Therefore one daemon would process modulo value 0 and the other would process modulo value 1.

987654321 % 2 = 1 so it would be processed by the daemon processing modulo 1.

4. I guess we could have a single daemon which divvies out the work to the processing daemons.  The processing daemons could communicate with this single daemon which I'll call the "work manager" via some IPC mechanism.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to implement logic in Python, you can use python's [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class.
It designed for exchanging data between multiple threads.

You can put your files and/or directories in queue, then each thread will access the queue and get that file. In that way, threads will never  hold the same object.

Comment: You'll need some good RPC library. You can check ZMQ for example: http://zeromq.org/

Comment: We don't plan to use python, but even if we did I'm not sure how what you're suggesting would work in a multi-node scenario.

Comment: It looks like, you're going to write kind of FileSystem bench-marking tool. You can check source code of Oracle's vdbench. They're implementing ideas you're talking about i.e processing multiple files form multiple hosts.